# How to prove that $(\tau^v)^* = \tau^{-v}$ for distributions?

Tags: distribution-theory, adjoint-operators

I remember reading once that the translation operator $\tau^v f := f(\cdot + v)$ satisfies $(\tau^v)^* = \tau^{-v}$ in the sense of distributions. I believe $*$ operator refers to the adjoint, and in this case it makes sense for e.g. $f,g \in L^2$ since
\begin{equation*}
    \int \tau^v f(x) g(x) dx = \int f(x-v) g(x) dx = \int f(z) g(z+v) dz = \int f(z) \tau^{-v} g(z) dz,
\end{equation*}
but how would one prove it for a general distributional $f$?

Comment: When you apply $\tau^v$ to a distribution $T$, the equalities you wrote are either still valid in the analogous ways, or part of the definition of $\tau^vT$

Comment: Are you certain that you remember correctly? It wasn't that the translation operator can be written as a convolution with a delta distribution: $\tau^v f(x) := f(x-v) = \delta_{v}*f$?